# Unsloved: OPENGL: Rendering multiple textures

Tags: java, opengl, rendering

I am testing something out in OpenGL and I can't seem to render multiple textures.
After trying to render one texture after another, that texture replaces the first one.
My player is in the top left corner:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuSLj.png

My code is:

Making the textures:

```
Texture grass = loadTexture("grass");
Texture playerTex = loadTexture("player");
```

The load texture method:

```
public static Texture loadTexture(String key) {
        try {
            return TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/" + key + ".png")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

My openGL init code is:

```
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(0, 720, 480, 0, -1, 1);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

And when I render my items with different textures:

```
public void draw() {
        if(playerTex != null) {
            playerTex.bind();
        }
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(x + width, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        }
        glEnd();

    }
```

And for my grass:

```
if(grass != null) {
            grass.bind();
        }
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        {
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(x, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f(x + width, y);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        }
        glEnd();
```

My x, y, and width are just some local variables.
Also don't be confused with the grass and the player using the same x and y since they have their own classes.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you ever bind the `grass` texture

Comment: Sorry, the code for my grass and the player rendering are the same, I should of mentioned that.

Comment: One thing I just noticed, very interesting if you ask me, if I switch the place of the way I create my textures, so for example load the texture of my player before my grass, it will make everything look like the grass... Maybe there is a problem with the loadTexture method?

Comment: Should I post all of my code?

Comment: No.  Just post the code where you bind your textures.  And what do you mean "my grass and player rendering are the same"?

Comment: Where do the `Texture` and `TextureLoader` classes come from? Are they something you wrote youself, or are you using some kind of toolkit?